# How to check ADF UIComponent visibility on server side?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, trinidad

Provided that I have an `UIComponent` (or, actually, an `UIXComponent`) instance, how can I check that it will be rendered visible? Checking the `visible` property on a component won't always work, because one of component's parents can also be invisible.

To clarify, I need to check it on rendering phase and on server-side.
I've managed to write my own recursive function that does this, but I'd like to know if there is some built-in way to do this in ADF. (like it is for the client side - `isShowing()` method)

Comment: Which jdev been do you use? You areaware you have to check rendered and the visible properties?

Comment: 11.1.1.5. Yes, I am. The code won't be reached at all if component is not `rendered`.

Comment: Why don't you just check visible property on all parents too?